# Check three given numbers

Tags: javascript

I would like to check 3 numbers:

- If the three numbers are same I have to display `30`,
- If two numbers are same I display `40`,
- Otherwise, I display `20`.

When, I enter 3 numbers for example:

```
8
8
8
```

The output displays

```
30
40
```

Normally, the output is `30`. Why is the value `40` added also?

[image]

```
let readline = require("readline-sync");

let nb1 = parseInt(readline.question("Enter nb1 please : "));
let nb2 = parseInt(readline.question("Enter nb2 please : "));
let nb3 = parseInt(readline.question("Enter nb3 please : "));


if (nb1 == nb2 && nb2 == nb3) {
    console.log(30);
}

if (nb1 == nb2 || nb2 == nb3 || nb3 == nb1) {
    console.log(40);
}

else {
    console.log(20);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `else if` for the second condition.

Comment: Did you mean for your second `if` to be an `else if`?  Because logically *every* time the first `if` is `true` then so will the second.

Comment: There both displayed because both the `if` resolve to `true`, use `else if` like Kelly suggest to prevent the second `if` from checking if the first `if` is `true` already

Comment: As an aside... This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  This should always be your first step when diagnosing an unexpected result of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second if in an `else if` block.
Both of the first two ifs are true when 3 numbers are equal.